# How to get path to item which is in <Image/> in UWP? Closed

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I want to get path to the item which is in Image(Xaml). I do flyout menu and want to copy image to clipboard, but i want that my program know on which image i click. Now I have this:

```
private async void CopyImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(here i must have the path);
            List<StorageFile> storageFiles = new List<StorageFile>(1);
            storageFiles.Add(file);

            var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
            dataPackage.SetStorageItems(storageFiles);
            dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

            try
            {
                Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you set the contents of this `Image`? If you use `BitmapImage` with a `UriSource` you could get the file path from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xerillio said, you could get uri scheme from Image [`Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source?view=winrt-18362) property, and use [`GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) to get storage file. For the detail steps please refer the following code.

```
private async void MyImage_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var souce = MyImage.Source as BitmapImage;
    var uri = souce.UriSource;
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
    List<StorageFile> storageFiles = new List<StorageFile>(1);
    storageFiles.Add(file);

    var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.SetStorageItems(storageFiles);
    dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

    try
    {
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```